# AdminLTE content-wrapper min-height issue

Tags: adminlte

It seems that Admin LTE sets the `min-height` value for ` and also the side bar.  For some reason, in my case, this value is getting calculated to be way higher than it should, which causes the side bar to be unnecessarily long.  See the screenshot below.

[image: Extra long sidebar]

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

you need add this to this body tag

> class="skin-blue fixed sidebar-mini sidebar-mini-expand-feature" style="height: auto; min-height: 100%;"

like this:

`<body class="skin-blue fixed sidebar-mini sidebar-mini-expand-feature" style="height: auto; min-height: 100%;"></body>`

this fix it, i have the same problem

Comment: Correct.  I've still not found a solution for this.

Comment: Any luck I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

this is a way to fix it. you can put these code to fix.js

```
function initFix(){
    $('body').layout('fix');
}

$(function(){
    setTimeout(initFix,0);
});
```

Comment: did u change the origin page, download again than have a try